# How to write a Bitmap out to a XML file

Tags: android

Might sound crazy, but it's what I need to do.  I want to take a Bitmap object and use the XMLPullParser/XmlSerializer to write this to a flat file.  Obviously I will need to read the XML tag back into a Bitmap object.

I have tried various things, similar to how I write and read Bitmaps from a database.

```
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();                
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream); 
            byte[] bitmapByte = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Where I get lost is once I write this out to my XML file as a String, I can never get it converted back properly.  Any pointers is appreciated.

Edit:
I want to provide a little more information. I am writing out a good deal of XML data for a backup purpose, so loading or writing time is of no concern.  This is not a main source of the data (main source is a SQLite database).  I do not want to have to write out a couple of very small (48x48pixel) images as well if I can help it.

I am reading in my XML using the XMLPullParser, which reads a String:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("someXmlTag")){
String someString = parser.nextText();
```

I am writing out my XML using the XmlSerializer, which writes a String:

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            serializer.setOutput(writer);
            serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            serializer.startTag("", "someTag");
                           serializer.text(someString);
```

So somehow I have to turn my Bitmap into a String and then turn that String back into a Bitmap. I will do some searches on Base64 to see if I get any good examples.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The `XMLPullParser` is, as its name suggests, a parser, it's not used to write XML. Your best bet is to store it as `Base64` like mentioned before.

Needless to say, this is going to take a lot of space for no good reason.

It will also be a lot slower to read back.

Comment: I have updated my post with some more information that clears up a few things.  I will do some searches on Base64 to see what my options are.